# I have a vintage set box with the kids on it. Should I continue collecting era appropriate pieces to refill it?

Tags: sets, vintage, value

I have an early vintage set box (with the boy and girl on the cover). I've been collecting vintage pieces in order to restock the box with the hope the complete vintage set will be desirable on the collectors market. Am I correct in my thinking? Or am I just working on a project with an imagined goal?

Comment: which set?  where are pictures of the box?

Comment: @chicks I just went out to the garage to take a pic. Sadly, a pic is not possible at this time. My cubbie hole has been rendered inaccessible due to holiday piling, shoving, and I doubt a pic will be possible until the new year. It's  a small set, has the kids and a blocky house on it.

Comment: All good.  Good luck with finding the rest of the pieces.

Answer (score 5):

Given the quality of LEGO bricks, I would argue that an original box filled with the correct amount of the correct bricks from the same time period as the box is INDISTINGUISHABLE from an opened box containing the original bricks after use, and as such I would recommend you continue your effort. Just make sure that the bricks are indeed from the correct period (i.e. Colors are right, LEGO vs. Pat. Pend. Vs no markings, hollow underside or tube or lattice, etc.). The only way for a collector to be absolutely sure of the authenticity of the box and its content is to buy a factory sealed box, which are extremely rare given the age.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I would start by looking at the price the full set is selling because I have been surprised recently to see box I was expecting to be vintage *treasures* selling at very reasonable prices...